# How to jump into CSS class definition in eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

We can jump into a class, method or variable definition/declaration with ctrl+click in eclipse.

Is there any way or plugin to jump into CSS files from JSP files directly?

For example how can I jump into the "top menu" definition on the css file that I've included in this JSP. My code snippet like this:

```
<div class="top-menu">
<!--some other things here -->
</div>
```

I've used ctrl+click in intelliJ before for this purpose.
Best Regards!